# left Join with right table filtered for every rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

- Customer: customer_id
- Order: order_id, customer_id, createdAt

I want to retry for every customer the only last order.

I tried to do this:

```
    SELECT C.customer_id, ORD.*
    FROM "Customer" as C
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT "Order".customer_id, "Order".order_id, "Order"."createdAt"
            FROM "Order", "Customer"
            WHERE "Order".customer_id = "Customer".customer_id
            ORDER BY "Order"."createdAt" DESC limit 1
    ) ORD ON C.customer_id = ORD.customer_id
```

but the result is:

| Customer.customer_id | Order.order_id | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null |
| 2 | null | null |
| 3 | 123 | 2022-03-04 |

The result is correct only for a customer. I lose the information of the others.

I also tried to do this:

```
    SELECT  C.customer_id, ORD.*
    FROM    "Customer" as C
    LEFT JOIN "Order" as ORD
    ON ORD.customer_id = (
                    SELECT  ORD.customer_id
                    FROM    "Order" as ORD
                    WHERE   ORD.customer_id = C.customer_id
                    ORDER BY
                                    ORD."createdAt" DESC limit 1
                    )
```

the result in this case is:

| Customer.customer_id | Order.order_id | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 119 | 2022-01-04 |
| 2 | 120 | 2022-01-04 |
| 3 | 123 | 2022-03-04 |
| 3 | 121 | 2022-02-04 |

I have more information about customer 3, when I just need the row where order_id is 123.

I've been working on it for a couple of days, could someone help me? Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL? You have mistakenly tagged your request with both.

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the most recent order for each customer. But the `LIMIT 1` in your subquery means you only get the single most recent order (for any customer).

Let's work out a subquery to get the most recent order for each customer. Start with the date of each customer's most recent order.

```sql
            SELECT customer_id, MAX(createdAt) createdAt
              FROM ORD
             GROUP BY customer_id
```

Then let's do an inner join to that subquery. This should get us the detail of the latest order for each customer. Test it to convince yourself it works properly.

```sql
        SELECT ORD.*
          FROM ORD
          JOIN ( 
                SELECT customer_id, MAX(createdAt) createdAt
                  FROM ORD
                 GROUP BY customer_id
               ) latest ON ORD.customer_id = latest.customer_id
                       AND ORD.createdAt = latest.createdAt
```

That's the subquery to use in place of the one you have.

```sql
SELECT C.customer_id, ORD.*
FROM "Customer" as C
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT ORD.*
          FROM ORD
          JOIN ( 
                SELECT customer_id, MAX(createdAt) createdAt
                  FROM ORD
                 GROUP BY customer_id
               ) latest ON ORD.customer_id = latest.customer_id
                       AND ORD.createdAt = latest.createdAt
    ) ORD ON C.customer_id = ORD.customer_id
```

This sort of thing probably works on multiple database vendors.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query.. Hope it will cover your requirement.

```
select
  cust.customer_id,
  max(ord.order_id) AS order_id,
  max(ord.createdAt) AS createdAt
from Customer as cust 
join "Order" ord on cust.customer_id = ord.customer_id  
group by cust.customer_id;
```

Comment: This is indeed a neat solution provided that order numbers are issued in ascending order. You may still want a left outer join for customers without any order.

Answer (score 0):

Your derived table (subquery in the from clause) only selects one row. Your are using a join syntax here that got deprecated in the early 1990s. Here is your subquery with an up-to-date syntax:

```
select o.customer_id, o.order_id, o.createdat
from "Order" o 
join customer c on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
order by o.createdat desc 
limit 1;
```

Or shorter without the superfluos join:

```
select customer_id, order_id, createdat
from "Order"
order by createdat desc
limit 1;
```

In your main query you join this to your customer table and the one row that the subquery produces does get joined. It's just not what you actually intended.

One way to get the last order per customer is by using a window function such as `ROW_NUMBER OVER` or `MAX OVER`:

```
select c.customer_id, ord.*
from customer as c
left join
(
  select 
    o.*,
    row_number() over (partition by order_id order by createdat desc) as rn
  from "Order" o
) ord on ord.customer_id = c.customer_id and ord.rn = 1
order by c.customer_id;
```

Here is another approach using a fetch with ties clause:

```
select c.customer_id, ord.*
from customer as c
left join
(
  select *
  from "Order"
  order by row_number() over (partition by order_id order by createdat desc)
  fetch first row with ties
) ord on ord.customer_id = c.customer_id
order by c.customer_id;
```

And here is the same with a lateral join:

```
select c.customer_id, ord.*
from customer as c
left join lateral
(
  select o.*
  from "Order" o
  where o.customer_id = c.customer_id
  order by o.createdat desc
  fetch first row only
) ord on true
order by c.customer_id;
```